# Vue.js - Axios sends multiple requests after v-if toggle

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-directives

I have the following where i can toggle the form (show/hide) using the v-if directive. I have noticed two anomalies when i toggle the form.

The first anomaly is that when i close the form and then reopen it, if i add a comment, axios is submitting multiple requests?

Secondly using the the v-if directive completely destroys the form element and rebuilds it. This means I'm unable to use any jquery validation on the form once its been toggled i.e. destroyed and rebuilt.

any ideas why axios is behaving this way after toggling the form?

I know I can use the v-show directive instead of the v-if to prevent the form element being destroyed but is there any other way to show hide the form and still use jquery validate. If I moved the form into a component would the v-if directive still have the same effect i.e. prevent me using jquery validate?

```
<div v-if="threadClosed">
       This thread is now closed
 </div>
 <div v-else>
      <form id="form" method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="add">
           <textarea v-model="newComment" id="comment"></textarea>
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
 </div> 

 <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="close">close</a> | <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="open">open</a>

 <script>
 var vm =  new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
       threadClosed: false,
       newComment: '',
       comments: [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "comment": "blah...",
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "comment": "blah...",
            }
            {
              "id": 6,
              "comment": "blah...",
            }
       ]
     },
     methods: {
           add: function (comment) {

              if (!$('#form').valid()) return false;

              axios.post("api/thread/add", { comment: newComment })
               .then((response) => {
                      $("#clear-dropzone").click();
                    this.comments.push(response.data);
              });
           },
           close: function () {
              axios.post("api/thread/close").then((response) => {

                    this.threadClosed = true
              });
           },
           open: function () {
              axios.post("api/thread/open").then((response) => {
                    this.threadClosed = false
              }); 
           }
     }
  });     
 </script>
```

Comment: I do not see any mistakes that could cause that issue. Can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Are you sure the "multiple requests" aren't just CORS pre-flight checks?

Comment: @Derek three requests are sent when i check the network tab. Two of those request are succesful and one fails. Not sure what CORS pre flight check are? Plus this is only happening when i toggle the form.

Comment: _"This means I'm unable to use any jquery validation"_ there are vue validators. While you can use vue with jquery, they may not play nice if not configured well. Any chance that jQuery could be causing the issues?

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: @Daniel yes you are right. I trigger a jquery event inside axios which is causing the multiple request. But it only happens after the v-if toggle i.e. after vue destroys the element and recreates it. Prior to any toggle the click event does not seem to generate any odd effect?

Comment: why not use a vue validator? like https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate https://github.com/appstract/vue-validate https://github.com/webzhao/vue-form-validator  etc.